# Json Object with backslash, How to read content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I have a json response like this,

```
 {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"error\":{\"type\":\"Duplicate user\",\"errorMessage\":\"Another user exists with this user name\"}}","status":409,"statusText":"Conflict"}
```

I need to show error message user like `data.responseText.errorMessage` But it shows error, I just removed '\' (Backslash) using `JSON.stringify(data).replace(/\\/g, "")` method. But I get a string as result by this.(given below)

```
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{"error":{"type":"Duplicate user","errorMessage":"Another user exists with this user name (9846184100)"}}","status":409,"statusText":"Conflict"}
```

I can't parse this to json object using `JSON.parse` But the result is `Unexpected token e`

Then how can I show the errorMessage?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The string you get is bad formed

Comment: No it isn't, but i think its a realy bad practise to do this like this

Comment: But wait, are you getting this response from an ajax request? Then there are much better ways to do this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string is perfectly valid as it is, but you must first parse the response text:

```
var response = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
alert(response.error.errorMessage);
```

Comment: Thanks brother, great answer, I struct with over few hours...!!